# Outsource some text fragments

Tags: include

I have to type many books in Latex, where some chapters are quite similar to each other.
My idea was to do one chapter in a directory and outsource the differences in a subdirectory where the main file is.

like this:

```
  CONTENT
  |
  |
  |---Book1
  |---differences
  |
  |---Book1
  |---differences
  |
```

The several book files would include the content file, while the content file includes the differences file.

My question now is: is it possible to NOT include the whole differences file? so I could say in the contents file:

```
 ...some text...
 \include code-fragment 1 from differences
...some other common text
\include code-fragment 2 from differences
```

so I would not have to make plenty differences files for everything that is not common.

I hope my question is clear :) Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the idea, WillAdams, it didn't work at first (maybe I made a mistake?), but if I put it the other way around it works:

The main file then looks like this:

```
  \documentclass[]{article}
  \usepackage{etoolbox}

  \newtoggle{one}\togglefalse{one}
  \newtoggle{two}\togglefalse{two}
  \begin{document}
  .1. ..some text...\\

  \toggletrue{one}
  \input{code-fragment}
  \togglefalse{one}

  2. ...some other common text\\

  \toggletrue{two}
  \input{code-fragment}
  \togglefalse{two}

  \end{document}
```

and the file code-fragment:

```
  \iftoggle{one}{
  different text to appear under `1'
  }{}

  \iftoggle{two}{
  different text to appear under `2'
  }{}
```

Comment: I always manage to mess up the simple binary stuff --- pasted stuff in the wrong order I guess --- glad you got it working.